# How to handle Copy-Item exceptions?

Tags: powershell, exception

I am writing a PowerShell script which uses `Copy-Item`. I would like to know what kind of exception will be thrown when `Copy-Item` fails to copy the files from source to destination?

From [this link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849793.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), I don't see what kind of exception will be thrown.

I want to handle the exception in case of failure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since PowerShell is based on .NET I would expect the exceptions that are defined for the [`CopyTo()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f0e105zt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`CreateSubdirectory()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h8dtw1d6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) methods:

- [ArgumentException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentexception(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [ArgumentNullException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentnullexception(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [DirectoryNotFoundException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directorynotfoundexception(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [IOException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ioexception(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [NotSupportedException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.notsupportedexception(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [PathTooLongException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.pathtoolongexception(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [SecurityException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securityexception(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [UnauthorizedAccessException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.unauthorizedaccessexception(v=vs.110).aspx)

However, in PowerShell I would simply catch all exceptions indiscriminately (unless you want to handle specific scenarios):

```
try {
  Copy-Item ...
} catch {
  $exception = $_
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 19):

Add the tag "-errorAction stop" to the Copy-Item call, within a Try-Catch, like below.  The errorAction throws an error which the Try-Catch can handle.

```
$filepathname = 'valid file path and name'
$dest = '\DoesntExist\'

try
{
    Copy-Item $filepathname $dest  -errorAction stop
    Write-Host "Success"
}
catch
{
    Write-Host "Failure"
}
```

Comment: Explanation: `Copy-Item` throws non-terminating errors, which are not handled by try-catch blocks. Using `-ErrorAction Stop` elevates the error to a script-termating error, much like those created with `throw`. Script-terminating errors are handled by try-catch blocks, and so the problem is fixed!